# Comparing dataframe cell value to previous cell value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to iterate through each row of a pandas dataframe and compare a certain cell's value to the same cell in the previous row. I imagined this could be done using `.shift()`, but it is returning a series instead of the cell value.

I have seen some usage of `groupby` and `iloc` for accessing the value of a cell but not for iterative comparisons, and using some sort of incrementing counter method or manually storing the value of each cell and then comparing doesn't seem very efficient.

Here is what I imagined would work, but no joy.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   if row['apm'] > df['apm'].shift(1):
      # do something
```

Comment: What do you want to do in the the #do something section?

Comment: What is `# do something` doing? This can be vectorised by checking `df.apm.diff() > 0`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, in this case, it is setting a value to a new column. I am determining if it is higher, lower or equal to the previous value and labeling it accordingly.

Comment: Can you provide your data and expected output please?

Comment: Print `df.head(10)` and paste its output in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a new column (e.g. `flag`) to indicate whether or not the boolean check is true.

```
df = df.assign(flag=df['apm'].gt(df['apm'].shift()))
```

Then you could perform your action based on the value of this column.

Comment: `df.apm.diff().gt(0)` ... But the question is, what is OP doing there...

Comment: Marginally faster. Which version is more clear is subjective.

Comment: There are some new things for me here, let me dig into it and get back to you, thanks!

Comment: So if I understand correctly, we are creating a new column, `flag`, to label all comparisons as either true or false. `.gt` determines if the current is greater than the previous cell. This would work for me in theory, but wouldn't that still try to compare a series like my original did? I think this is the part that I'm failing to understand, and while a solution is my primary goal I'd also like to understand what I am doing wrong too. Thanks

Comment: Your interpretation is correct.  `iterrows` is much slower than a vectorized solution such as the one I provided, which operates on the columns.  What are you seeking to do when the condition is true?

Comment: @Alexander that's good to know, it was running slowly but I wasn't sure if it was because of the error or not. I want to add to another column whether it is higher, lower or equal. It is important I am comparing cell values and not whole rows as there are several columns for different things in each row.

Comment: @nghs you should be using np.where or np.select. Can you provide some of your data in your question please?

Comment: @nghs You are comparing the cell values of adjacent rows for the `apm` column.  @COLDSPEED is correct. Sample data with expected output goes a long way in providing optimal suggestions.

Comment: The values are simple floats: `1.12`, `1.43`, etc. I've never heard of `np.where` or `np.select`, I'm pretty new to python, so let me dig into those real quick

Comment: @alexander this seems to work, but what if I wanted to assign a value to the field like `higher`, `lower`, `equal_to`, how would I do that?

Comment: @nghs`equality = df['apm'].gt(df['apm'].shift())` `df = df.assign(flag=np.where(equality.gt(0), 'higher', np.where(equality.lt(0), 'lower', 'equal_to')))`

Comment: awesome, let me put that to work, and sorry for the delays, been wicked busy all of a sudden

Comment: This is probably better and just one line:  `df = df.assign(flag=np.sign(df['apm'].sub(df['apm'].shift())).map({1: 'higher', -1: 'lower', 0: 'equal_to', np.nan: np.nan}))`

Comment: @Alexander sorry for the late reply, found a lot of stuff here I didn't understand so spent the time to learn about it. This solution, with some minor tweaks, worked as intended. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
df['apm'].shift(1)
```

returns a series with previous values for each row, except for None in the first row.
Thus, the code

```
df['apm'] > df['apm'].shift(1)
```

will return the series with boolen values, also `True` or `False` for each row.
Would that be enough for your task?

Comment: Is it comparing cells from the same column in both rows? If so, then that would work, but if it is comparing the whole row to the previous row then it would not work.